# Отображение NULL при использовании GROUP BY

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

Есть таблица с результатами тестирования:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо отобразить средний тестовый балл школ по математике **(код предмета - 2)**:

```
SELECT schoolid, avg(TestResult100) av FROM result
WHERE SubjectCode = 2
GROUP BY SchoolID
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Математику сдавали только учащиеся из школы **1001** и конечно же в результирущей таблице отобразился результат только этой школы. Но как отобразить результат школы **1002**?

Да, да я знаю - SQL Server отобразил все правильно, согласно сделанному запросу. Хотелось бы составить такой запрос, чтобы результатом было, что-то на подобии:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли возможность составить SQL-запрос для вывода такой информации?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT schoolid, avg(case SubjectCode when 2 then TestResult100 end) av 
FROM result 
GROUP BY SchoolID
```

Answer (score 1):

LEFT JOIN в помощь: выбираете все школы, а потом объединяете с результатами.

```
SELECT s.SchoolID, avg(r.TestResult100) av
FROM result s
LEFT JOIN result r ON s.SchoolID = r.SchoolID
WHERE s.SubjectCode = 2
GROUP BY s.SchoolID
```